# What are the .load() constants we can pass?

Tags: office-js

New to JavaScript and the Office API in general. Just getting my feet wet. There is a lot to learn. I see different string constants passed to the load() function call, like "name" or "address". What are these and how do we find them? There is no intellisense for it.

For example

```
getRange.load('address')
```

or

```
table.load("name")
```

TIA,
Zack Barresse

Comment: Btw, I did read this thread, the only thing I could find which was close, but it's not all inclusive:

https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/blob/master/excel/resources/loadoption.md

Comment: Buidling on Michael's Answer: IOW, Zack, anything that pops up in Intellisense for the object you're loading is valid as a parameter. So when you type table. the properties in the list that comes up after . contains what you can use as parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason to call the "load" method is because you intend to access it after the ctx.sync(), right.  E.g., say you have code that wants to output the current selection's address:

```js
Excel.run(function(ctx) {
    var range = ctx.workbook.getSelectedRange();

    // <do some load on the range>

    return ctx.sync().then(function() {
        console.log(range.address);
    })
}).catch(function(e) {
    console.log(e);
})
```

Because you see yourself doing `range.address` (and that you should see enumerated in IntelliSense), it means that you know that's the property name that you should have loaded.  And in fact, if you forget, you'll get a failure where you try to access it, and it should tell you that the property has not yet been loaded.

The only caveat is for collections:  when you do tables.load("name"), you're really telling the tables collection "load all your child objects, pre-fetching the name". So there, instead of looking for IntelliSense off of the table object directly, you should look for how you'll access the child properties (i.e., tables.items[0].___)

Hope this helps,

~ Michael Zlatkovsky, developer on Office Extensibility team, MSFT